# File access and modification through a web site

Tags: asp.net

I want to access a file (a Microsoft Office file, e.g., Word, ppt, exl) through a web application and modify it and save it. The changes done for the file should be saved to a file location on the server.

If the file is accessed by another user, other users should be notified. (Just like SharePoint does.)

Please help me on this.

Comment: I hope that you not imaging to modify it inside the web page. The next think is the download, and upload with some warning messages.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can go about doing this. But right off the top of my head, might I suggest using System.IO.File to open the file for writing. You could set some sort of a flag to tell if the file is currently opened and check that flag every time the file is being viewed.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC SharePoint manages file sharing/versioning via a database, not on the file system. and for office files you would want to open and modify them locally, not within a webpage.

and what you describe sounds very much like version control. In which case you are better off using an existing product rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

i was working on a project to export gridview data to xsl, i found out that i can write xsl as html ! And it opens with microsoft exel, i suggest you open your file in editor for example ckeditor and moify it then save it.